# Saving a bool to NSdefaults on AppWillTerminate not working

Tags: nsuserdefaults

I am trying to logout a user when the application is terminated (since in this particular case the user data doesn't change very often there is no need to logout when going into background).

So here is my code:

```
    - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
   {
        User *user = [[User alloc]init];
        [user logout];
   }
```

I first tried to log the user out like so but it didn't work:

```
   - (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
  {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"logged_in"];
  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the defaults to be updated immediately, you should sync after updating:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

As documented (khm, please **look up the documentation**), the `NSUserDefaults` class doesn't immediately persist the changes to disk, only once in a while.

Comment: I tried to syncronize but in the appwillterminate is not working. If i put the sync statement in the appWillResignActive it works but that means that the user must be reauthenticated on every applicationDidBecomeActive and thats a waste of internet data. But thanks anyway

Comment: @DanPrecup It should work. Make sure that method is called at all.

Comment: I finally gave up, and went with enter background-foreground action